# SSRS 2008 R2 Subreport Displays Only on First Page

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, nested, subreport

Long time browser of this site, but first time poster.  Normally I'm able to find the answer I need by searching, but in this case I haven't been able to, and it's driving me nuts!

I'm using BIDS / SSRS 2008 R2 to create a membership renewal form which my business will mail out to our customers.  The form contains customer information, including membership dues / subscription info and other billing details.

In order to accomplish this,

**I have built three RDLs:**

1. Main report (this is one the users run).  Contains base data set
   (let's call it Proc 1), which requires an expiration date only, to
   pull a list of member IDs and corresponding physical information
   (address, phone, membership type, etc.)  Contains the first subreport,
   in a list, grouped by member ID.
2. One subreport for the first page in the main report.  Contains a
   set of parameters for each field it needs.  Rather than execute Proc 1
   again, I pass Proc 1's output from the main report to this subreport.
   Everything in this subreport is also contained within a list, grouped
   by member ID parameter (passed from main report).
3. Another subreport, nested within the first subreport, which pulls
   subscription information.  First subreport passes member ID and paid
   through date to detail data set in nested subreport (let's call it
   Proc 2).  Proc 2 requires paid through date from page one subreport,
   and ONE member ID, which it gets from its parent report.  It displays
   this information in a table, not grouped, since it should only be
   receiving one ID at a time--- being that its parent subreport. and the
   main report. are already grouped.  However, I have tried grouping the
   table based on member ID, and it didn't make a difference.

I found this approach necessary, because of the fact that I had two write two separate stored procs: one to pull the basic data, and one to pull detailed billing data.  It's impossible to combine the two without creating duplicate rows.  And of course, it's not possible to have a tablix assigned to a different data set than the list it is contained within.  Hence the need for a subreport.  I hope that all makes sense.

Anyway, my issue is that the nested subreport only displays data for the first customer.  In fact, it doesn't display the nested subreport AT ALL for the rest of the customers.  It's as if the nested subreport is only being passed the first member ID, but I don't see how that's possible given the grouping?  Note that I am not using any FIRST or aggregate functions in the proc or report expressions.  And I can execute each report file just fine individually.

I have tried creating a dummy data set in the nested subreport (ex. SELECT 'Nothing' AS Nothing) and adding it to a text box, thinking that this would force the nested subreport to display, but it STILL doesn't.  Thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your setup sounds OK to me.  Note testing in BIDS has many bugs, secret caches and is kinda meaningless anyway (assuming your end users dont use BIDS).  I usually deploy everything to an SSRS server and run all tests there.  It's also more convenient as you can leave multiple windows open and just refresh them.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's the same behavior on our SSRS server.  It's as if the subreport is only being passed the first ID, but I can't see what would cause that.  I also tried moving the table from the subreport into the main report, in its own separate list, which is not contained in the main list, and it exhibits the same behavior.  So odd...

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f8b9c42-90cb-4620-ad91-9754029ed4db/seemingly-random-error-subreport-could-not-be-shown-in-a-report-with-nested-subreports-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Your nested subreport could be throwing an error that your not seeing.

Quote

The known issue in SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967749 should be fixed in SQL Server 2008 R2. Generally, the issue occurs because the parameter value is not passed to the subreport correctly or the subreport is not valid due to the specific values passed to the subreport.

I think you should add a detail group then put the subreport in that cell.  Make sure the grouping is working correctly and pass the right values to the subreport.